# std::thread Run code in object

Tags: multithreading, c++11, std, stdthread

How can I start a thread executing code from another object/class?

This is what I tried, but didn't work

```
#import <thread>
#import "Foo.h"

int main() {
    Foo bar;

    std::thread asyncStuff(bar.someMethod);
}
```

So why doesn't this work, and how can I solve it?

Solution:
Call `std::thread asyncStuff(&Foo.someMethod, &bar);` instead.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: `#import`? What is `bar.someMethod`? What error are you getting and what don't you understand about it? What does the `std::thread` documentation/standard say it takes as argument(s)?

Comment: @Mat How is bar.someMethod relevant? The question is how to use threads when the code is in another object.

Comment: @KaareZ: it matters because it could be a static member function, a non-static member function, or a pointer-to-data-member, all of which are supported and do slightly different things. As you'd have found out by reading the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
std::thread asyncStuff(&Foo::someMethod, &bar);
```

(Don't forget to join or detach the thread before destroying the `std::thread` object.)